# How do I correctly describe a thing that has been subject to Currying?

Tags: adjectives, names

[Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is a particular technique from the field of logic with an important application to programming languages. Currying a function that expects multiple arguments yields a higher-order function that expects one argument. The technique is named after Haskell Curry, who made it popular.

I am searching for the proper adjective to describe the resulting function. It is tempting to call it the *curried* function. In fact this is often used and will probably be understood by the audience but is it also correct? 
I am uncertain, because of the difference between the name "Curry" and the verb "to curry".

edit: Because there seems to be some confusion, I want to make it clear that I am not searching the common adjective (which is "curried"), but rather the proper one. For instance, I could also write "Curried" to indicate that the word is the derivative of the name. But is it even appropriate to change the "y" in the name to a "ie"?

How do you create the past participle of a name that has been turned into a verb?

Comment: Please do your research thoroughly. The Wikipedia article you link to contains 'All "ordinary" functions that might typically be encountered in mathematical analysis or in computer programming can be curried.' Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I am well aware of the wikipedia article, but wikipedia is hardly authoritative regarding the english language. Just because this is the common adjective it is not necessarily correct.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, which is for questions about **how** to do something, not what to call it. However, [softwareengineering.se] might be suitable. There is already at least one question which actually mentions [currying](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152868). That said, the last line of this question is on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewLeach. I had thought that at first, too, then I thought I had seen some software engineering questions on there unrelated to how, which is why I had continued to suggest it. Meanwhile, yes, the Software Engineering SE would be the better choice. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't bother trying to find a 'more authoritative' source than Wikipedia because you yourself seemed to think it adequate. Dual standards? // Trying to discover the present acceptability of a new sense some wish to apply to a word, or, as here, a new candidate word ('curry' must be seen as a homonym if and when it enters the lexicon), is very difficult for some time and remains largely a matter of opinion. Applying 'rules of parallel behaviour' can be unsafe, as changes can take place: 'mouses', 'no-hitted' etc.

Comment: Not dual standards at all. I cited wikipedia for the definition of Currying, which is correct (I am quite familiar with the subject). I do not trust the article when it comes to language, though. I find answers on this site somewhat more authoritative in that regard, but this is of course a personal opinion.

Comment: I have rarely found reason to query more recent (2010 ...) articles in Wikipedia. Notice that in the answer you accept, just one anecdotal reference to the past tense usage and no references at all for the usual conjugation patterns of new verbs are given. I'd say Wikipedia trumps that (though I didn't think an 'answer' suitable here on ELU without better references). // I actually agree with the bulk of the answer you accept, but ELU protocol virtually demands authoritative references for answers.

Comment: @choeger - When you talk about "proper" vs "common", do you mean proper in the sense of "proper noun" or in the sense of "correct"? I may have misunderstood, and if I have then my answer is pretty much useless...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a name is turned into a verb, then it's a verb and follows normal rules. The only caveat might be that it could retain its capital letter if it is not fully genericised.

*Hoover* is a name, but *hoover/hoovered* is a normal verb (meaning to use a vacuum-cleaner: Hoover was one of the first brands of such appliances).

*Google* is a name which has become a verb and has more-or-less lost its proper capital to become *google/googling/googled*. Google don't particularly like it (although their attitude softened between [2003](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/3006486.stm) and [2013](http://www.nbcnews.com/technology/no-googling-says-google-unless-you-really-mean-it-1C9078566)), but it's entered the language and been subjected to normal rules of verb formation.

*Curry* may be a name, but *curry* already exists as a verb with a particular meaning (to add curry spices to something), so it's perfectly unexceptional to use its normal form *curried* as a past participle for your word. Whether you feel your use should use a capital letter is a matter of style. It was certainly in use without a capital letter in 2013:

> Currying alone is essentially useless, but having all functions curried by default makes a lot of other features much nicer to use. — [C. A. McCann](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/26921/c-a-mccann) [Feb 1 '13 at 20:13](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185585/what-is-the-advantage-of-currying#comment357036_185585)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I imply that. "*Curry* is **also already** a word...", so a new word will be a duplicate [homonym]. But surely it will follow the same rules, because language finds a level which works. It's highly unlikely that *Curryed* will gain traction now.

Comment: I've encountered far too often on ELU statements like " 'bear' is a word that means 'carry' or 'grizzly' ". It's essential on such a site that people see that there are two entirely different words involved.

Comment: Hmm. I see. Perhaps the adjusted answer makes the distinction clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make it clear that I am not searching the common adjective (which is "curried"), but rather the proper one.

Why wouldn't what is already commonly done be "proper"? As far as I can see it, the crux of your question is:

> How do you create the past participle of a name that has been turned into a verb?

You, personally, don't need to. Other people have already done it. They came up with **curried**. This is commonly accepted as the past participle *therefore it is the **proper** past participle*.

The English language isn't prescribed by anyone, it is the sum of how people use it. As long as both parties understand the same thing when a word is used, that word is completely fine. Neologisms may go through a period where there are competing spellings / conjugations, but they normally settle into one being more popular and winning out.

As there is no competing term here, **curried** has already won.

Comment: I think the "common" and "proper" were used in the sense of "common nouns and proper nouns." Lowercase "curried" is certainly consistent, but is uppercase "Curried" acceptable or should it be "Curryed" because the capitalization marks a proper noun, which usually don't have the y > i(e) change? I think that was part of the question.

Comment: @sumelic - Good point, I hadn't thought of that. I've asked OP for clarification.

Comment: @sumelic - I read the question as asking for the right term to use, and the right spelling.